# Power BI: Measure as Category for Visuals

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I have a requirement which I am not able to solve.

The requirement is:
[image]

From the above table, Calculating the "% of Revenue" is percentage of sum of revenue to the grand total Revenue.

measure "Margin Bucket" tells in which bucket does "% of Revenue" falls into.
I have to use "Margin Bucket" measue in X-axis, I will be using it for Clustered Column Chart and Matrix.

I have added the link of  the sample pbi file. Please help.[Link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FamafchyS7EesRNazhbzGHjaGBRIsg6e/view?usp=drive_link)

I created a table where I added selectedvalue as the percentage bucket but that is not giving me accurate results

Output:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zWkwL.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use Measures as "dimensions".

Looking at your data model and need, try the following:

1. **Add a new table** similar to this. Let's call it `Margin Bucket`.
   Then click on the `Bucket` column and do `Sort by column` `Bucket sort`.

| Bucket | Min | Max | Bucket sort |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| < 0% |  | 0 | 1 |
| 0 - 15% | 0 | 0.15 | 2 |
| 15 - 30% | 0.15 | 0.3 | 3 |
| 30 - 45% | 0.3 | 0.45 | 4 |
| 45 - 60% | 0.45 | 0.6 | 5 |
| > 60% | 0.6 |  | 6 |

2. **Create a new measure** with the below.
   This measure will return true/false, which we will use in other measures shortly.

```
In Margin Bucket = 
  var bucketV =
    DIVIDE(
      SUM(Sheet1[Revenue]),
      CALCULATE(SUM(Sheet1[Revenue]), ALLSELECTED(Sheet1)),
      0
    )
  var rngMin = MIN('Margin Bin'[Min])
  var rngMax = MAX('Margin Bin'[Max])
  return SWITCH(TRUE(),
    NOT ISINSCOPE('Margin Bin'[Bucket]), TRUE(),
    ISBLANK(rngMin) && bucketV < rngMax, TRUE(),
    ISBLANK(rngMax) && bucketV > rngMin, TRUE(),
    rngMin <= bucketV && bucketV < rngMax, TRUE(),
    FALSE()
  )
```

3. **Update any measures** that you'd like to use in visuals with `'Margin Bucket'[Bucket]` - with an `IF` statement. For example:

```
Revenue M = IF([In Margin Bucket], SUM(Sheet1[Revenue]))
```

For completeness - you can update your `% of Revenue` measure with the below. Note how we `REMOVEFILTERS('Margin Bucket')` for the grand selected total.

```
% of Revenue = 
  DIVIDE(
    [Revenue M],
    CALCULATE(
      [Revenue M],
      ALLSELECTED(Sheet1), REMOVEFILTERS('Margin Bucket')
    )
  )
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: Hi,  Thank you so much for the detailed explanation. However, I will be using the bucket as dimension, Do you think that is possible with above method.(Please refer to the picture I have added in the question which is the output I am expecting)

Comment: Yes, the new table is your new dimension. My picture in the answer, both visuals are using this method.

Comment: How did this go?